# rails 3.1, how to integrate JavaScript in View?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript

I would like to know please, what is the proper way to enable/ disable an element at page ?

I have a view, but, I don't know the best way to do it ?? 
Is there a quick helper or gem that would access any element at page and set its HTML properties ?

Shall I put a function in a coffee file and call it from view ? how would I do so ??

Is there a good tutorial to see about integrating coffee or JavaScript with View using the new asset pipeline at Rails 3.1 ??

Comment: You're going to have to clarify this question. When you say "enable/disable an element," what exactly do you mean? When do you want to do so: When you first serve the page from the server, or in response to some user input event?

Comment: I blogged on this a while ago, maybe this will help answer some of your questions? http://house9.blogspot.com/2011/05/rails-31-javascript-execution.html

Comment: Thanks Trevor, I want to disable the element when I first the page from the server, this should be easy, but what I am asking about to disable or enable in response to some user input event, I will check the link, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution ( for an href link )

in haml, it would be:

```
:javascript
                $('#'+NEXT_PAGE_ID).attr('href', 'javascript: void(0)');
                $('#'+NEXT_PAGE_ID).attr('style', 'color: #888888');
```

I've changed the color to dark gray to look as in-actve ..